# JInternalFrame Image display;

Tags: java, image, paint, repaint, jinternalframe

I tried adding an image to JInternalFrame. my paint() looks like this:

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        //this should draw the loaded image
        if (bufferedImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(bufferedImage, getSize().width/2 - bufferedImage.getWidth()/2,
            getInsets().top+20, this);
        }
    }
```

The image does load and display, but the window title bar (the one that should have the name, min, max and close) disappears. The min/max/close buttons reappear when I move the mouse to where they should be, and when I move the mouse over the title bar I can drag
the whole window.

Should I be using something else instead of the paint() method?

thanks

Comment: swing custom painting must be done in paintComponent (instead of in paint)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have good reason to directly draw into the `JInternalFrame`, why not create a `new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufferedimage))` and just `add()` it to the `JInternalFrame`?

An example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class PictureDesktop extends JDesktopPane {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        // some Wikipedia Commons Pictures of the Day
        final URL url1 = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Hacienda_jaral_de_berrios.jpg/300px-Hacienda_jaral_de_berrios.jpg");
        final URL url2 = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/Magellanic_penguin%2C_Valdes_Peninsula%2C_e.jpg/300px-Magellanic_penguin%2C_Valdes_Peninsula%2C_e.jpg");
        final URL url3 = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Marmolada_Sunset.jpg/300px-Marmolada_Sunset.jpg");

        final PictureDesktop desktop = new PictureDesktop();
        desktop.addPicture(ImageIO.read(url1));
        desktop.addPicture(ImageIO.read(url2));
        desktop.addPicture(ImageIO.read(url3));

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pictures");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, desktop);
        frame.setSize(720, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addPicture(final Image image) {
        add(createFrame(image));
    }

    private static int frames;

    private JInternalFrame createFrame(final Image image) {
        frames++;

        final JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("Picture " + frames);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
        // without pack and setVisible, the frame isn't shown
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // cascade frames 
        frame.setLocation(40 * frames, 40 * frames);

        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm missing something - where does the repaint work? I can't see the label as it is.

Comment: Check out the code example I posted, maybe you missed `pack()` and `setVisible()`. If you use Swing components, there's no need for manually requesting repaints.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be working. I've canceled the repaint(), so it's empty now, and I put loading the buffered Image into a JLabel in the constructor, with packing and setVisible(true), but this made things worse - now I can't see the internal frame...

Comment: Could you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your current code as an edit to your question? I can't help you further without more context.

Comment: Thanks, but I got a different solution - put the JInternalFrame in an outer class and extend it to include an image panel. I've tried labels before, but they gave me some weird results.

Comment: Could you post your latest comment as answer and accept it so this question gets closed? Thank you :)